# Get list of Rave Reports in delphi

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I have a Rave Report Project that contains few reports ( 4 to 6) and I would like to add them into a combobox so that the user can select which report he wants to use. How can I get the list of Reports i've got into the Rave Report Project and pass it to the combobox.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 i: Integer ;
 list : TStrings;
begin
   RvProject1.GetReportList(list,True)   ;
        for i := 0 to list.Count - 1 do

    ComboBox1.AddItem(list[i],nil);
end;
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work, i get an `Access Violation at adress...` error.
Anyone can help me with a solution?

Comment: You must instantiate your `list` before passing to that method.

Comment: Thank you, it works now, I post the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution. I've had to make an instance of the `list` string list passed to the `GetReportList` method:

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  list: TStringList;
begin
  list := TStringList.Create;
  try
    RvProject1.GetReportList(list, True);
    ComboBox1.Items.Assign(list);
  finally
    list.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Without testing: `RvProject1.GetReportList(ComboBox1.Items, True);` without a separate `TStringlist` instance  might work, too.